# How to derive the distribution of 1 - X if X is Beta(0.5, 1)

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, beta-distribution

[image]

I've been reading about uniform distributions and I'm wondering how statisticians derive these distributions. Lets say we have X, a random variable from the Beta(0.5, 1) density. How could you derive the distribution of Y = 1 − X?

Comment: Since the question is tagged `cumulative-distribution-function`, it is perhaps reasonable to ponder that _for continuous random variables_ $X$,  $$F_{1-X}(\alpha)= P(1-X \leq \alpha) = P(1-\alpha \leq X) = P(X\geq 1-\alpha) =1-F_X(1-\alpha)$$

Comment: Another approach would be to draw a graph of the density of a $X \sim \text{Beta}(a,b)$ r.v. and another of $1 - X$. Afterwards, consider the expression for the PDF.

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate how did you get the last part $=1-F_X(1-\alpha)$

Comment: $P(X \geq 1-\alpha) = 1 - P(X \leq 1-\alpha) = 1 - F_X(1-\alpha)$.

Comment: @jbowman Ohh okay. But how can we derive a distribution from $1 - F_X(1-\alpha)$ ?

Comment: The CDF is of $X$ is not difficult to find, so use the CDF method to find the CDF of $Y$ and hence its PDF and distribution.

Comment: Change the variable "$x$" to "$1-x$" in the density function.  What is the new density?

Comment: Alternatively, use an appropriate characterization.  For instance, a Beta$(a,b)$ distribution [arises as the ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Derived_from_other_distributions) $X/(X+Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ independently have Gamma distributions with parameters $a$ and $b,$ respectively. Because $1-X/(X+Y)=Y/(X+Y),$ the result is immediate and fully general: $Z$ has a Beta$(a,b)$ distribution if and only if $1-Z$ has a Beta$(b,a)$ distribution.

Comment: Please don't repost your question: edit it to clarify it and if that works, the question will be reopened.  Our [help] explains more about how this site works.